# Rails pagination duplicate rows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, pagination, will-paginate

I am getting duplicate entries when I fire sql query with offset 0 and 50. Employment has many feedbacks. Database is PG. I have tried sorting also by feedbacks.uuid and employments.uuid, but with no success. Where is the catch please? What is making me more confused is, that the sorting on first two pages (offset 0 and 25) is ok. The third page is messed up and contains entries from page 1. However if I fire the sql without limit and offset, everything is ok. The problem occurs only when I am doing pagination.

```
all_staff = Employment.includes(:feedbacks, :user, venue: [:venue_account]).with_roles(1)
            .where("CONCAT(employments.first_name, ' ', employments.last_name) LIKE ?", name).references(:employments)

@staff = all_staff.reorder("feedbacks.updated_at DESC NULLS LAST").references(:feedbacks).limit(25).offset(0)
```

Fired SQL queries:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "employments" WHERE "employments"."role" = 1 AND (CONCAT(employments.first_name, ' ', employments.last_name) LIKE '%%')

SELECT DISTINCT "employments"."uuid", feedbacks.updated_at AS alias_0 FROM "employments" LEFT OUTER JOIN "feedbacks" ON "feedbacks"."employment_id" = "employments"."uuid" LEFT OUTER JOIN "users" ON "users"."uuid" = "employments"."user_id" LEFT OUTER JOIN "venues" ON "venues"."uuid" = "employments"."venue_id" LEFT OUTER JOIN "venue_accounts" ON "venue_accounts"."venue_id" = "venues"."uuid" WHERE "employments"."role" = 1 AND (CONCAT(employments.first_name, ' ', employments.last_name) LIKE '%%') ORDER BY feedbacks.updated_at DESC NULLS LAST LIMIT 25 OFFSET 0

SELECT "employments"."uuid" AS t0_r0, "employments"."first_name" AS t0_r1, "employments"."last_name" AS t0_r2, "employments"."picture" AS t0_r3, "employments"."state" AS t0_r4, "employments"."about" AS t0_r5, "employments"."visible" AS t0_r6, "employments"."role" AS t0_r7, "employments"."position" AS t0_r8, "employments"."kpi" AS t0_r9, "employments"."kfi" AS t0_r10, "employments"."venue_id" AS t0_r11, "employments"."user_id" AS t0_r12, "employments"."started_at" AS t0_r13, "employments"."ended_at" AS t0_r14, "employments"."kpi_updated_at" AS t0_r15, "employments"."created_at" AS t0_r16, "employments"."updated_at" AS t0_r17, "feedbacks"."uuid" AS t1_r0, "feedbacks"."text" AS t1_r1, "feedbacks"."last_manager_conversation_id" AS t1_r2, "feedbacks"."last_user_conversation_id" AS t1_r3, "feedbacks"."first_manager_conversation_id" AS t1_r4, "feedbacks"."conversations_count" AS t1_r5, "feedbacks"."state" AS t1_r6, "feedbacks"."visible" AS t1_r7, "feedbacks"."last_manager_reads" AS t1_r8, "feedbacks"."last_user_read_at" AS t1_r9, "feedbacks"."settled_at" AS t1_r10, "feedbacks"."opened_at" AS t1_r11, "feedbacks"."left_at" AS t1_r12, "feedbacks"."last_active_at" AS t1_r13, "feedbacks"."user_id" AS t1_r14, "feedbacks"."employment_id" AS t1_r15, "feedbacks"."venue_id" AS t1_r16, "feedbacks"."created_at" AS t1_r17, "feedbacks"."updated_at" AS t1_r18, "feedbacks"."application_type" AS t1_r19, "users"."uuid" AS t2_r0, "users"."first_name" AS t2_r1, "users"."last_name" AS t2_r2, "users"."email" AS t2_r3, "users"."picture" AS t2_r4, "users"."about" AS t2_r5, "users"."badge" AS t2_r6, "users"."manager_badge" AS t2_r7, "users"."thanks_count" AS t2_r8, "users"."solved_count" AS t2_r9, "users"."not_solved_count" AS t2_r10, "users"."created_at" AS t2_r11, "users"."updated_at" AS t2_r12, "venues"."uuid" AS t3_r0, "venues"."response_rate" AS t3_r1, "venues"."name" AS t3_r2, "venues"."picture" AS t3_r3, "venues"."venue_category_id" AS t3_r4, "venues"."employee_of_day_id" AS t3_r5, "venues"."thanks_count" AS t3_r6, "venues"."latitude" AS t3_r7, "venues"."longitude" AS t3_r8, "venues"."foursquare_id" AS t3_r9, "venues"."foursquare_about" AS t3_r10, "venues"."about" AS t3_r11, "venues"."created_at" AS t3_r12, "venues"."updated_at" AS t3_r13, "venues"."new_venue_category_id" AS t3_r14, "venue_accounts"."uuid" AS t4_r0, "venue_accounts"."status" AS t4_r1, "venue_accounts"."expires_at" AS t4_r2, "venue_accounts"."user_id" AS t4_r3, "venue_accounts"."venue_id" AS t4_r4, "venue_accounts"."visible_new_thanks" AS t4_r5, "venue_accounts"."visible_new_solved_feedback" AS t4_r6, "venue_accounts"."visible_new_not_solved_feedback" AS t4_r7, "venue_accounts"."created_at" AS t4_r8, "venue_accounts"."updated_at" AS t4_r9 FROM "employments" LEFT OUTER JOIN "feedbacks" ON "feedbacks"."employment_id" = "employments"."uuid" LEFT OUTER JOIN "users" ON "users"."uuid" = "employments"."user_id" LEFT OUTER JOIN "venues" ON "venues"."uuid" = "employments"."venue_id" LEFT OUTER JOIN "venue_accounts" ON "venue_accounts"."venue_id" = "venues"."uuid" WHERE "employments"."role" = 1 AND (CONCAT(employments.first_name, ' ', employments.last_name) LIKE '%%') AND "employments"."uuid" IN ('64342810f25749c99dced3e4a94733bb', '090acd676f7b46a29af14865a495bf6b', 'e3b0a2e509fe49d1a018a9b2524bcaab', '42891e3c5f4b4b60b8c6d8009ea92c6f', 'e3b0a2e509fe49d1a018a9b2524bcaab', '8f88a65466a3499a8fe7d2b13d79a7ce', 'e248efe594094c0aaefc578d285d188c', 'e248efe594094c0aaefc578d285d188c', '581bce76e1114ce99e068b59362d39d4', 'd9f9a6eba7184069ae500b430a222294', '39b5e272cd8b4e8e95286f93db2c81a3', 'c9d86838815949d0acfc96d0048eb398', 'd9f9a6eba7184069ae500b430a222294', 'd32a33c77fb94e289a2ef54ed6f34761', 'd9f9a6eba7184069ae500b430a222294', '581bce76e1114ce99e068b59362d39d4', '2849ed41f0254f518dbf0b9551ce1552', '581bce76e1114ce99e068b59362d39d4', '581bce76e1114ce99e068b59362d39d4', 'd9f9a6eba7184069ae500b430a222294', '581bce76e1114ce99e068b59362d39d4', 'd9f9a6eba7184069ae500b430a222294', '39b5e272cd8b4e8e95286f93db2c81a3', 'd32a33c77fb94e289a2ef54ed6f34761', 'd9f9a6eba7184069ae500b430a222294') ORDER BY feedbacks.updated_at DESC NULLS LAST
```

In case with offset 50 is the first modified as

```
SELECT DISTINCT "employments"."uuid", feedbacks.updated_at AS alias_0 FROM "employments" LEFT OUTER JOIN "feedbacks" ON "feedbacks"."employment_id" = "employments"."uuid" LEFT OUTER JOIN "users" ON "users"."uuid" = "employments"."user_id" LEFT OUTER JOIN "venues" ON "venues"."uuid" = "employments"."venue_id" LEFT OUTER JOIN "venue_accounts" ON "venue_accounts"."venue_id" = "venues"."uuid" WHERE "employments"."role" = 1 AND (CONCAT(employments.first_name, ' ', employments.last_name) LIKE '%%') ORDER BY feedbacks.updated_at DESC NULLS LAST LIMIT 25 OFFSET 50
```

P.S. I use the will_paginate gem, which in this case displays no pagination div, despite of
@staff.total_pages == 11

Comment: You have two queries and you don't show a single result. I'm confused by your question.

Comment: My problem is that 
`@staff_1 = all_staff.reorder("feedbacks.updated_at DESC NULLS LAST").references(:feedbacks).limit(25).offset(0)`
and
`@staff_2 = all_staff.reorder("feedbacks.updated_at DESC NULLS LAST").references(:feedbacks).limit(25).offset(50)`
have some object which are contained in both variables.

Comment: Can you paste both queries (you can get a query by appending `.to_sql`)?

Comment: Theay are way too long because of the including. Each call (@staff_1 and also @staff_2) produces two queries.

First query SELECT DISTINCT employments.uuid, feedbacks.updated_at LEFT OUTER JOINS feedbacks, users, venues, venue_accounts ORDER BY feedbacks.updated_at DESC NULLS LAST LIMIT 25 OFFSET 0

The second query SELECT everything, LEFT OUTER JOINS tables WHERE employments.uuid IN (uuids retrieved in prev. query) ORDER BY feedbacks.updated_at DESC NULLS LAST with no limit, nor offset

@staff_2 produces same queries, except the offset in first is not 0 but 50

Comment: I can paste them in question section.  
Whats driving me crazy is, that without LIMIT and OFFSET, is everything OK. And with LIMIT and OFFSET is messed up also ordering... First two pages are dates from 21.7. to 17.7. and then on third page are dates again from 21.7.

Comment: Your comments are hard to read, could you please just update the question with this information?

Comment: I am sorry for my English, also my explanation skills are not very good. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: No problem. Ability to clearly explain a problem is valuable and everyone has to learn it over time. And there's nothing wrong with your English! :)